# Tooltip(title attribute) is getting truncated

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Scenario:
I am working on a product where i need to display list of displaynames(single string without spaces), the display name length limitation is 256 char, so a user can choose a single string with 256 char long.

Issue:
Select Option tags are used to display the names:-

```
      <select id="fileshares_0_0" name="fileshares_0_0">
              <option selected="" title="TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST">TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTE...</option>
      </select>
```

This truncates the title when hovered over the selected option.
Solution requested is to display the complete Title text.

Comment: You probably need [a custom select](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same issue. After some testing, it seems that this is a FF (at least on 22) issue only. IE8 and Chrome properly wrap the text.

Please note that if there are spaces into the title, then the title gets broken in FF too. There was a Bug for that in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45375) that is apparently solved. However they didn't solve the bug where the title contains no spaces.

Your best bet for a fix would be either to look for a bug in the Mozilla database or create a new one.

Hope that I have helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the Tooltip css is causing the title to truncate? Overflow: hidden could be set on the parent element that has a fixed width/height.